# Library/framework to share the same codebase for J2ME and Android versions of an app?

Tags: android, java, cross-platform, mobile

I recall I had seen such a thing on GitHub, but lost the link, and can't find it again. AFAIR, it provided an abstraction layer for APIs of both platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging questions from different StackExchange sites seems to be not supported for now, so here is a link to duplicate:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988/what-work-has-been-done-on-cross-platform-mobile-development

Even though that question is more broad, there are answers that refer tools with J2ME and Android support.

[RAMP](http://ramp.virtualmobiletech.com/) seems to be still alive, others (MoSync, MoMinis, Phonsai) are dead.